# C program loops infinitely after scanf gets unexpected data

Tags: c, scanf

I have a program where I want the input integer to be between 2 and 64 inclusive, so I put `scanf` inside a `do { ... } while` loop. Here's the code I initially tested:

```
int initialBase;

do {
  printf("Initial base: ");
  scanf("%i", &initialBase);
} while (initialBase < 2 || initialBase > 64);
```

The problem is whenever the input is not a valid integer, it just outputs the `printf` statement indefinitely and no longer prompts for user input, instantly flooding the console. Why is that happening and what's a better way of reading input that satisfies the conditions I want?

Comment: Anyone care to comment why I'm being downvoted?

Comment: It's not odd, that's just how scanf() works.

Comment: Well, why does it stop prompting?

Comment: Because there's already buffered data. scanf doesn't discard it because it couldn't be parsed.

Comment: I wasn't one of the downvoters, but I suspect you've been downvoted because there's a plethora of posts on stackoverflow.com describing issues with using `scanf` for user input. A common recommendation is to not use `scanf` but to use `getline` or something similar, and then post-parse the string.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm new to C and my professor requires us to use this function to read input, that part was not my decision.

Comment: @indiv I rolled back your edit because it's kind of pointless to ask that, that would be asked by someone who knows the answer, don't you think?

Comment: @iharob:  No, I don't think that.  That's exactly the question being asked:  "The problem is whenever the input is not a valid integer, it just outputs the printf statement indefinitely and no longer prompts for user input, instantly flooding the console. Why is that happening...".  I just put it in the title.

Comment: I rolled back to @indiv 's edit because I think it's a more accurate statement as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `scanf()` fails, the argument is not automatically initialized, and uninitialized values could be any value, so it might be less than `2` or greater than `64` no one knows.

Try this

```
int initialBase;

/* some default value would be good. */
initialBase = 2;
do {
  printf("Initial base: ");
  if (scanf("%i", &initialBase) != 1)
      break;
} while ((initialBase < 2) || (initialBase > 64));
```

the check will break out of the loop if you input something that is not a number, the initialiazation of `initialBase` is just a good habit which in your case could have prevented the behavior you describe, but in this case it's there to prevent accessing an uninitialized value after the `while` loop.

The reason the loop didn't stop, was because `scanf()` leaves some characters in the input stream when they are not matched, and calling `scanf()` again while those characters are still there will make `scanf()` keep waiting for valid input, but returning immediatly with the currently invalid input that is in the stream, if you want to keep reading, try reading characters from the stream until a `'\n'` is found, this way

```
int initialBase;

initialBase = 0;
do {
    printf("Initial base: ");
    if (scanf("%i", &initialBase) != 1)
    {
        while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
        continue;
    }
} while ((initialBase < 2) || (initialBase > 64));
```

Comment: So basically you're saying I can't continue prompting for valid input if the user puts something like "a"?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You can but you have to clear unread characters from the input stream, for which `fflush()` is not the solution. Check my new posted code.

Comment: Do I have to ``#include`` something besides ``<stdio.h>`` for ``fgetc``?

Comment: No, just `<stdio.h>` for both, `fgetc()` and `scanf()`. Use compiler warnings, it would save you a lot of time, for instance wierd things might happen when you forget an `#include` and they could be prevented if you make your compiler complain about everything.

Comment: Yes I use ``gcc -Wall main.c -o main`` so it should output all warnings at compile time.

Comment: make it `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` you will be pissed off first, but then you will be very happy... And sometimes you can also add `-pedantic` to make you even more pissed off...

Comment: @iharob: Well, I trade `-Werror` for `-std=c11 -pedantic`. And then eliminate all those warnings, for everything but short discard-in-5-minutes tests.

Comment: I keep the `-Werror` always, it's a good way of preventing that feeling when you find out you made a stupid syntax error or something similar, and wasted more than 10/20min or much more on that.

Comment: @iharob Your solution is very robust but I noticed one more problem: the user is prompted once more than necessary after inputting an integer that satisfies the ``while`` expression.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It doesn't happen in my case, are you sure you are using identical code?

Comment: Yes, I narrowed down the problem: the user must input an integer twice in a row, the first one must be an integer that satisfies the ``while`` expression, and the second one must be any valid integer. It then escapes the ``while`` loop with the first of the two input integers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts How are you testing the program? with an IDE or someting?

Comment: Nope, just using the terminal on OSX.

Comment: Should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you could, but I don't think there is a problem with the program itself, try the same code in a new program putting this code in `main()` and nothing else, and if it happens again, may be post a new question, if it doesn't check your program to see what else could be the cause.

Comment: Strangely enough, the exact same code behaves properly on its own. The only difference I think I can see in the main program is that I declare ``initialBase`` like this: ``int i = 0, j = 0, initialBase = 0, ...;``

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem, it was really dumb... thanks for all your help.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts when you post code on stack overflow you should not omit things like initialization, in the code you posted `initialBase` was not initialized, and that's why I point that out. It's just advice for your future posts. A recommendation, post a new question with the new problem and try to find the minimal possible program that reproduces the poblem. It will help you improve your debugging skills, and it will be easier to answer.