# Verifying Input in C

Tags: c, input, integer

I'm trying to write a simple binary calculator to get reaquainted with C.  for some reason the first input verification works fine, and even though the second verification for the numbers is written in almost the same way, if the user enters faulty input, the while loop just loops infinitely without ever waiting for new user input.  Here is the code, and thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char operator[20];
  char valid_operator[4] = "+-*/";
  printf("Enter operator: ");
  scanf("%s", operator);
  printf("You entered: %s\n", operator);
  while(strchr(valid_operator, (int)operator[0]) == NULL) {
    printf("%s is not a valid operator.  Enter +, -, /, or *: ", operator);
    scanf("%s", operator);
  }
```

The code works up until here.  This next part is thrown into an infinite loop if the user enters faulty input the first time.  The re-prompting never happens.

```
  int input1;
  int input2;
  printf("Enter the two inputs (separated by whitespace): ");
  int num_ints = 1;
  num_ints = scanf("%d %d", &input1, &input2);
  printf("Input 1: %d.  Input 2: %d.\n", input1, input2);
  while(num_ints < 2){
    printf("Invalid input.  Enter two integers separated by whitespace: ");
    num_ints = 0;
    num_ints = scanf("%d %d", &input1, &input2);
    printf("Input 1: %d.  Input 2: %d.\n", input1, input2);
  }
  return 0;
```

Comment: I bet it's about newlines..

Comment: use fgets to read from keyboard, use sscanf to extract from the string

Comment: `strchr(valid_operator, ...)` will not work, because its definition lacks a `\0` terminator, essential for string operations. Try `char valid_operator[] = "+-*/";` Because you limited its size to `4` no terminator is present in the array.

Comment: char valid_operator[4] - you're not allocating the null terminator? change it to const char* valid_operator = "+-*/";

Comment: The "strchr(valid_operator, (int)operator[0]) == NULL" check is working fine.  It correctly asks for valid input until one is given.  It's the SECOND check that isn't working.  If the user enters "1 3" it passes, but if they enter "1 t" or "t 1" it falls into an infinite loop.
Edited the main post to make this clearer.  Thanks for all the responses so far.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf is asking for surprises.

Comment: The invalid input `"t"` *stays in the input buffer* no matter how many times you `scanf` it with the `%d` format specifier. The easiest way to get round this is to input to a string with `fgets` and then when the `sscanf` on that string fails, you can easily get a fresh input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear stdin.  If you input a non-integer in your example "1 t", "t" is not consumed (left in the stream).  Add this to your loop:

```
while(num_ints < 2){
   while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n'); // clear input
. . .
```

See [C program loops infinitely after scanf gets unexpected data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176928/c-program-loops-infinitely-after-scanf-gets-unexpected-data) for a good description of the issue.

Comment: ahh I suspected that something like this was happening.  This fixes the issue.  I still don't understand why faulty input is consumed in the first case, but not in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it *loops infinitely without ever waiting for new user input* is that when `scanf` fails to read a char in the requested format (`%d` in your case) **it won't advance** the file pointer and at the next iteration of the loop it will try to read the same incorrect char again.

This is consistent with POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html

> if the comparison shows that they are not equivalent, the directive shall fail, and the **differing** and subsequent bytes **shall remain unread**.

Also, return value from the `man scanf`:

> ...return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So, you better combine `fgets` and `sscanf`.

```
do {
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    printf("Enter the two inputs (separated by whitespace): ");
    if(fgets(buf, BUFSZ, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        /* Error exit. */
        break;
    }
    num_ints = sscanf(buf, "%d %d", &input1, &input2);
} while(num_ints != 2);
```

Comment: Result of `fgets` should be checked too but +1.